# android set list item custom background color

Tags: android, listview, background-color

I need to set a custom color to a list item based on a property of item from adapter and I can not use a selector (condition for item to have custom color is an item property, not a selected or focused state). In getView method I set

```
view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.blue)
```

but this does not works because it doesn't matter what color I set for background, the result is the same. I tried to set background color to the layout but the result is the same. Can you please give me a clue? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use ,

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue)
```

it will work.

Comment: WHYYYYYYYYYYYYY? This is so frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.Gray));
```

Comment: I did not down vote you..I have just edited your answer to make your code line more readable... :)